# Permission denied on directory with specific name

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, server, permissions

This is a weird one... On Ubuntu 14.04 I have a directory called `/lib`. As root, or on the server as a user with group privileges, I can write to this directory. Over FTP as the same user with group privileges I cannot, I get a **Permission Denied** error...

If I rename the `/lib` directory to anything else (in this case `/lib-new`) I **can** write to the directory over FTP.

What could be causing a **Permission Denied** error based purely on the name of the directory?

I've checked and tested the permissions of the directory (777, 775, 755, 664 and 644) as well as the directory above (`/public_html` - the root directory for the server) and nothing helps, unless I rename the directory something other than `lib`.

Please help, as SSH-ing into the server to make changes to anything within `/lib` is time consuming!

EDIT: The FTP server I'm using is ProFTP if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `RLimitChroot off` to `/etc/proftpd.conf`.  May need to restart X for this change to take affect.  By default, I think it will do the same thing to `/etc` directory as well.

Comment: You're an absolute legend. That worked and I just went and RTFM on this one. Thank you so much! I can't see how to have this enabled, but make an exception for /lib within virtual host directories, but I'll have a scout around. Thanks again :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good idea to write to `/lib` and even less to rename it on a server

Comment: It's a path to a directory called `/lib` not the root `/lib` directory (i.e. `/var/www/host/httpdocs/lib`.